# C server code - Java Client Code TCP Connection Problem

Tags: java, c, tcp, connection, client

I have a server - client java code and the server part has to be written in c.
The first part of the code (server side) is to receive multicast message from the client and then connect to client with a tcp connection and send some message. With my c code I can receive the multicast message from the client but when I try to make a tcp connection I get an error. The c server can not make a tcp connection with the java client. I am posting both the codes below. If you can find the problem please let me know. Thanks.
**IPMulticastDiscoveryClient.java Client code**

```
package org.postgresql.discovery;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;
import org.postgresql.discovery.ClientTCPResponseProvider;
/**

* A feature for detecting remote service addresses (IPs) via IP Multicast.

* 

* Each service must first bind itself with the help of the IPMulticastDiscovery Server

* and is identified with a unique name.

* 
* 

*

*/

 public class IPMulticastDiscoveryClient {
private static String myIp = null;

public IPMulticastDiscoveryClient(){

}

/**

 * Locates a bound service with a unique name via IPMulticast

 * 

 * @param service unique name of the service

 * @return the IP address of the service as String

 * @throws Exception

 */

public String getIpForService(String service, String host) throws Exception{

    //CloudCacheLogger.info("Looking for service: " + service);

    // 1. open a response channel

    ClientTCPResponseProvider response = new ClientTCPResponseProvider(service);

    // 2. multicast request

    sendJoinCluster(service, host);

    // 3. collect response

    //if(response.getFinalResult() == null){



    //}

    try {

        Thread.sleep(1000);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }



    String result = response.getFinalResult();

    //myIp = result.split(";")[1];

    //result = result.split(";")[0];



    // 4. close the response channel

    response.destroy();

    // 5. check

    if(result == null){

        throw new Exception("Could not discover service: " + service);

    } else {

        //CloudCacheLogger.info("found service: " + service + " at " + result);

        return result;

    }

}



/**

 * Uses a remote service to discover the local, external IP address

 * 

 * @param service unique name of a remote service

 * @return the local, external ip address

 * @throws Exception

 */

public String getMyIpFromService(String service) throws Exception{

    if(myIp != null)

        return myIp;

    else throw new Exception("could not determine local ip");

}



private static void sendJoinCluster(String message, String host){

    try {

        System.out.println("\nIn sendJoinCluster");

        InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName(host);

        MulticastSocket s = new MulticastSocket(9876);

        s.joinGroup(group);

        DatagramPacket hi = new DatagramPacket(message.getBytes(), message.length(),group, 6789);

        s.send(hi);

        s.leaveGroup(group);

        s.close();



    } catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}



public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {

    IPMulticastDiscoveryClient client = new IPMulticastDiscoveryClient();

    String result = client.getIpForService("FindIP", "228.5.6.7");

    System.out.println(result);

}

}
```

**ClientTCPResponseProvider.java**

```
package org.postgresql.discovery;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
* Offers a socket for receiving repsonses from remote services. Once the client 
sent  a location
* request, it waits for messages to arrive on this Socket.
* 
* 
*
*/
public class ClientTCPResponseProvider {

private ServerSocket providerSocket;
private Socket connection = null;
private ObjectOutputStream out;
private ObjectInputStream in;

private boolean endConnection = false;

private String keyword = null;
private String finalResult = "";

public ClientTCPResponseProvider(String keyword){
    System.out.println("\nIn ClientTCPResponseProvider");
    this.keyword = keyword;
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadedProvider());
    t.start();
}

public void destroy(){
    endConnection = true;
    try {
        providerSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void goConnect(){
    try{
        System.out.println("\nIn goConnect.");
        //1. creating a server socket
        providerSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
        //2. Wait for connection

        Object message = null;

        long timeout = 1000;
        long initTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        do{
            //System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
            connection = providerSocket.accept();
            //System.out.println("Connection received from " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
            //3. get Input and Output streams
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            //4. The two parts communicate via the input and output streams
            try{
                message = in.readObject();
                String response = (String)message;
                //System.out.println("received: " + response);
                if(response.startsWith(keyword) && response.split(":")[0].equals(keyword)){
                    finalResult += connection.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()+";";
                    System.out.println(" IVAN " +finalResult);
                    //finalResult += connection.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress()+ ";";
                    //endConnection = true;
                }
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException classnot){
                System.err.println("Data received in unknown format");
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
            connection.close();
        } while(System.currentTimeMillis()-initTime < timeout);
        providerSocket.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class ThreadedProvider implements Runnable{
    //@Override
    public void run() {
        goConnect();    
    }
}

public String getFinalResult() {
    return finalResult;
}
```

}

**Server code in C**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *listenToClient();
char *trim(char *str);
void sendMessageToClient(char *ip, int *port, char *message);

#define HELLO_PORT 6789
#define HELLO_GROUP "228.5.6.7"
#define MSGBUFSIZE 256
char *ClientIP = "localhost";
char *HostIP = "192.168.164.138";
int isRunning = 1;
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
pthread_t thread;
int th;
th = pthread_create( &thread, NULL, listenToClient, NULL);
pthread_join( thread, NULL);    
exit(0);
}

 void *listenToClient(){
 struct sockaddr_in addr;
 int fd, nbytes,addrlen;
 struct ip_mreq mreq;
 char msgbuf[MSGBUFSIZE];

 u_int yes=1;                

 /* create what looks like an ordinary UDP socket */
 if ((fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0)) < 0) {
  perror("socket");
  exit(1);
 }

/* allow multiple sockets to use the same PORT number */
if (setsockopt(fd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&yes,sizeof(yes)) < 0) {
   perror("Reusing ADDR failed");
   exit(1);
   }

 /* set up destination address */
 memset(&addr,0,sizeof(addr));
 addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
 addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
 addr.sin_port=htons(HELLO_PORT);

 /* bind to receive address */
 if (bind(fd,(struct sockaddr *) &addr,sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
  perror("bind");
  exit(1);
 }

 /* use setsockopt() to request that the kernel join a multicast group */
 mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr=inet_addr(HELLO_GROUP);
 mreq.imr_interface.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

 if (setsockopt(fd,IPPROTO_IP,IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,&mreq,sizeof(mreq)) < 0) {
  perror("setsockopt");
  exit(1);
     }

do {     
  addrlen=sizeof(addr);
  if ((nbytes=recvfrom(fd,msgbuf,MSGBUFSIZE,0,(struct sockaddr *) &addr,&addrlen)) < 0) {
       perror("recvfrom");
       exit(1);
  }
  puts(msgbuf);
      char message[] = "FindIP:192.168.164.138 (Some IP)\n");    
  printf("\nSending Message To Client: %s\n", message);
      sendMessageToClient(ClientIP, 8888, message);
}while(isRunning==1);
close(fd);
}

  /**Sends the messages to the remote machine
  * ip = Address of the machine where message has to sent
  * port = port used for sending the message
  * message= string message
  *
  */
  void sendMessageToClient(char *ip, int *port, char *message) {
int sockfd, portno, n;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
struct hostent *server;

char buffer[256];

portno = port;
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0)
    error("ERROR opening socket");
server = gethostbyname(ip);
if (server == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no such host\n");
    exit(0);
}
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy((char *) server->h_addr, (char *) &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
        server->h_length);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    error("ERROR connecting");
bzero(buffer, 256);
strcpy(buffer,message);

n = send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
if (n < 0)
    error("ERROR writing to socket");
bzero(buffer, 256);
close(sockfd);
return 0;
    }
```

Comment: "I can an error" - what error?!

Answer (score 0):

```
portno = port;
```

I suspect you want

```
portno = *port;
```

Comment: No I don't think that's the problem. if I change portno to *port I get segmentation fault.

Comment: Are the apps running on the same machine?

Comment: No c server code and java client are running on different machines. The problem occurs at connect() call in c. It says connection refused.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of this function is incorrect:

```
void sendMessageToClient(char *ip, int *port, char *message)
```

The type of `port` should be `int`, not `int *`.  The code always connects to `localhost:8888`, regardless of where the client message came from; is that what you intended?

By the way, you are using a lot of obsolete functions in your C code (like `bcopy()`, `bzero()` and `gethostbyname()`).

Comment: I have changed the int * port to int port but still the same problem persists. I am trying to connect to another machine with ip of 192.168.164.138. I was thinking I am passing the right address by using this -> bcopy((char *) server->h_addr, (char*)serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @rmd22: `server` is the result of `gethostbyname(ip)`, and `ip` is equal to `ClientIP` which is `"localhost"`.

Comment: @caf: even if i change localhost to clientip, it still can not connect to the client. :(

Comment: @rmd22: If you want more help you will have to say exactly what the error is (which function is failing, and what is the error code).

Comment: @caf: The error happens at connect() call. It says connection refused. That's the only error i am getting.

Comment: @rmd22: In that case, `localhost:8888` is not listening or is firewalled.